# Why is this array not being passed?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

Simple script sending form data to a PHP script to be processed. The data in in an assoc array and output to the console shows it is present. Data is passed using a jquery AJAX function, however the PHP script is not receiving array. However, if I hardcode the data into the function, the data is passed.

If have tried setting the AJAX function 'method' to POST and also removing that option. I have tried different formats for the array. Passing the array as part of a hard coded array.

Javascript side

```
function saveInformation(e) {
            var d       = []
            var f       = $(e)[0].id; //Form name
            var formData    = $('#'+f).serializeArray();

            formData.forEach(function(item){
                d[item.name] = item.value;  
            })


            console.log('data',d)

            $.ajax({
                data:       d,
                url:        "TableUpdate.php"
            })
            .done(function(e) { $('#agentGeneralInfoTitle').text('Agent General Information (Saved)'); console.log(e);})
            .fail(function(e) { 
                alert("save failed\n" + e.responseText);  console.log(e);
            });

        }
```

The console.log command shows data in variable d. All the data is present and properly formatted.

PHP side

```
<?
require_once('/var/www/Debugging/ChromePhp.php');
chromePHP::log($_REQUEST,$_POST);
:
:
:
?>
```

this prints out "[],[]". It complete correctly with a determination that the data is not present.

I expect the data to be passed and the chromePHP::log to show an array with data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var d` should be an object not array.

Arrays have numeric indices only in javascript

Change

```
var d = []
```

To

```
var d = {}
```

---

Also using `serialize()` instead of `serializeArray()` would make it simpler as you wouldn't need to loop through and create `d` at all

```
  function saveInformation(e) {
        // assuming `e` is form element
        var formData    = $(e).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            data:       formData    ,
            url:        "TableUpdate.php"
        })
        .done(function(e) { $('#agentGeneralInfoTitle').text('Agent General Information (Saved)'); console.log(e);})
        .fail(function(e) { 
            alert("save failed\n" + e.responseText);  console.log(e);
        });

    }
```

Comment: ###@&*@^#*&@#@#!!!!!!!! Blank, blanky, blank, blanky, blank....... I searched for that stupid error for 8 hours and missed that I used the wrong ^*&&^@*#$ bracket!! Thank you for your help.

Comment: See update using `serialize()` which is even easier